# Aerobic respiration

Tags: respiration

I read a sentence in my biology book while i was reading respiration chapter.  i wasnot able to understand it. It was in the process of oxidative phosphorylation"
"as the proton pass through channel their electrical potential energy is used to synthesise ATP in a process called CHemiosmosis" Can anyone plz explain that from where this energy came in proton and how is it transfered during facilitated diffusion.!